# What are real-world use cases for start-exclusive ranges/intervals?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, continuity

Having a continuous range that is start-inclusive and end-exclusive is helpful for bucketing, binning, and histograms. There are countless cases for continuous ranges that are start-inclusive and end-inclusive (defining the span of a graph axis, an acceptable range of values, etc).

But what about ranges that are start-exclusive/end-inclusive or start-exclusive/end-exclusive? Are there real-world applications for those? Can you list any applications in practical mathematical modeling, statistics, machine learning, industry, etc?

Comment: Actualy, as soon as continiuous ranges are at work, there is - in real life - no differnce between $[a,b)$, $[a,b]$, $(a,b]$, and $(a,b)$. Then again, I don't see a reason why a statistician should not choose to group,into say, "up to 9000" vs. "over 9000"

Comment: I don't know if I agree with that, although I know what you're saying. Building a histogram should never have a boundary shared between two bins. That programmatically-speaking is bad.

Comment: @tmn: Your 'rule' about binning is sometimes a convenience when data are discrete. Sometimes it makes 'ugly' interval boundaries. Whenever making a graphical description of data, always consider your audience and the message you are trying to convey to them. // For ages of people do you really want bin boundaries 29.5 and 49.5? // The convention whether to use intervals like $(a, b]$ or like $[a, b)$ seems to vary from country to country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Examples:** Here are test scores from a statistics class with 50 students, sorted in order of increasing size. (Brackets [] give the index of the first
number printed on each row.)

```
sort(x)
 [1] 78 79 80 81 81 81 81 82 82 82 82 83 83 83 83 84 84 84 84 85
[21] 85 85 85 85 85 85 85 86 86 86 86 86 86 87 87 88 88 88 89 89
[41] 89 90 90 90 90 91 91 91 91 93
```

Below are four frequency histograms of the data. All might be considered reasonable
for various purposes. The first histogram uses the default binning programmed into R.
The binning of each of the other three is shown by the `br` parameter:
first endpoint, last endpoint, and interval width. R uses intervals of type $(a,b],$ unless otherwise instructed. (Bins of the last histogram correspond to letter grades.)

The `rug` procedure
indicates which numerical values are present in the sample (There are not 50
tick marks because of ties.) R tends to label the x-axis with round numbers,
even if they are not exact bin boundaries.

```
 par(mfrow=c(2,2));  hdr = "Fifty Test Scores"  # 'par' permits 4 panels per plot
  hist(x, col="skyblue2", main=hdr);  rug(x)
  hist(x, br = seq(77.5, 93.5, by=1), col="skyblue2", main=hdr); rug(x)
  hist(x, br = seq(75, 95, by=5), col="skyblue2", main=hdr); rug(x)
  hist(x, br = seq(74.5, 94.5, by=5), col="skyblue2", main=hdr); rug(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # return to single-panel plots
```

[image]